# Is there any way to generate Alphabetic Sequence with Current Year In SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

How can we write a SQL function which can generate 'Sequence_Code' like AA,AB,AC....AZ. BA,BB,BC.... with the combination of last two digit of 'Current_Year' for each 'ID'.
Order by 'Record_Date'

For instance: If Current_Year of First row is is 2019, then Sequence_Code  should be 19AA.
My table is LoadData

| Sequence_Code | ID | Current_Year | Record_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NULL | 310001 | 2019 | 2019-01-01 |
| NULL | 310002 | 2018 | 2018-02-22 |
| NULL | 310003 | 2020 | 2020-02-20 |
| NULL | 310004 | 2020 | 2020-02-10 |

Expected Output is:

| Sequence_Code | ID | Current_Year | Record_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 19AA | 310001 | 2019 | 2019-01-01 |
| 18AB | 310002 | 2018 | 2018-02-22 |
| 20AC | 310003 | 2020 | 2020-02-20 |
| 20AD | 310004 | 2020 | 2020-02-10 |

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: You say it's "Order by `Record_Date`" and yet your expected output has the earliest record assigned `AB` rather than `AA`?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks for remonstrating the mistake, I have made correction.

Comment: @Alin do you want to update the table or just a select statement?

Comment: Yes i want to update the Sequence number of the table,like whenever i get a new record in the table , This function should generate the next Sequence_Code,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `ROW_NUMBER()` window function and math:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Record_Date) rn FROM LoadData)
SELECT RIGHT(Current_Year, 2) + 
       CHAR(ASCII('A') + rn / 26 + CASE rn % 26 WHEN 0 THEN -1 ELSE 0 END) + 
       CHAR(ASCII('A') - 1 + CASE rn % 26 WHEN 0 THEN 26 ELSE rn % 26 END) Sequence_Code,
       ID, Current_Year, Record_Date
FROM cte
ORDER BY rn
```

If you want to update the column `Sequence_Code` of the table:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Record_Date) rn FROM LoadData)
UPDATE cte
SET Sequence_Code = RIGHT(Current_Year, 2) + 
                    CHAR(ASCII('A') + rn / 26 + CASE rn % 26 WHEN 0 THEN -1 ELSE 0 END) + 
                    CHAR(ASCII('A') - 1 + CASE rn % 26 WHEN 0 THEN 26 ELSE rn % 26 END)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e0713c843b49e17b1368cb4cdab77339).
Results:

```
> Sequence_Code |     ID | Current_Year | Record_Date
> :------------ | -----: | -----------: | :----------
> 18AA          | 310001 |         2018 | 2018-01-01 
> 19AB          | 310002 |         2019 | 2019-02-22 
> 20AC          | 310004 |         2020 | 2020-02-10 
> 20AD          | 310003 |         2020 | 2020-02-20
```

Comment: The code is working fine, But some changes i have done in my Question, Is there any way we can alter this code according to the Condition i have given?

Comment: @Alin no, this is a different requirement for which you should post a new question and not edit the current question, because this way you invalidate the answers that you already have received.

Comment: Thanks for the code,I have updated this post with the previous Question which i asked Initially and you answered it Properly. I am posting the new Requirement in another post..As you suggested..please Do reply if there is any convenient way to write Code for that condition.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method might be to generate all combinations and enumerate them:

```
with alpha as (
      select 'A' as alpha union all
      select 'B' as alpha union all
      . . .  -- continue for the rest of the letters
      select 'Z' as alpha
     ),
     alphas as (
      select concat(a1.alpha, a2.alpha) as alpha2,
             row_number() over (order by a1.alpha, a2.alpha) as seqnum
      from alpha a1 cross join
           alpha a2
     )
select current_year || alpha2.alpha2 as sequence_code, t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by current_year order by record_date) as seqnum
      from LoadData t
     ) t left join
     alpha2 
     on t.seqnum = a2.seqnum;
```

Note:  This uses standard SQL, so the functionality may have different syntax depending on the database.

Comment: i am not getting proper output, can you please provide me the above code  by using table Name and Proper column names. My table Name is' LoadData'