# Is there any way to generate Next Alphabetic 'Sequence Code' For Specific ID's In SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, sql-server-2017

I have gained some help from this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65494479/is-there-any-way-to-generate-alphabetic-sequence-with-current-year-in-sql/65504843#65504843), still need some further assistance.

How can we write a SQL Function which can generate Next Sequence_Code for only those ID's which are having Status 'A'.

Note: If Table is already having Some Sequence_Code,it should be as it is,there should not be any changes,But if Sequence_Code is not there in the table,
then function should generate next Sequence_Code. i.e  before generating a Sequence_Code, ,it
should check the previous Sequence_Code, then it should generate the next one.
For every New ID(With Status 'A'),It should generate the next Sequence_Code.

Alphabetic 'Sequence_Code' must be combination of last two digit of 'Current_Year' and 2 character alphabet like AA,AB,AC....AZ,
BA,BB,BC...BZ.  CA,CB,CC....

For instance: If Current_Year is 2017, then Sequence_Code should be 17AA.

My table is 'LoadData':

> | Sequence_Code | ID | Current_Year | Record_Date | Status |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 17AA | 310001 | 2017 | 2017-01-01 | S |
> | 18AB | 310002 | 2018 | 2018-02-22 | S |
> | 19AC | 310003 | 2019 | 2019-02-10 | S |
> | 20AD | 310004 | 2019 | 2019-02-20 | A |
> | 20AE | 310005 | 2020 | 2020-03-20 | S |
> | NULL | 310006 | 2020 | 2020-04-20 | A |

Epected Output is:

> | Sequence_Code | ID | Current_Year | Record_Date | Status |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 17AA | 310001 | 2017 | 2017-01-01 | S |
> | 18AB | 310002 | 2018 | 2018-02-22 | S |
> | 19AC | 310003 | 2019 | 2019-02-10 | S |
> | 20AD | 310004 | 2019 | 2019-02-20 | A |
> | 20AE | 310005 | 2020 | 2020-03-20 | S |
> | 20AF | 310006 | 2020 | 2020-04-20 | A |

Please Suggest if there is any convenient way.

Comment: @forpas This is the current condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply a `WHERE` clause for the current conditions:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Record_Date) rn FROM LoadData)
UPDATE cte
SET Sequence_Code = RIGHT(Current_Year, 2) + 
    CHAR(ASCII('A') + rn / 26 + CASE rn % 26 WHEN 0 THEN -1 ELSE 0 END) + 
    CHAR(ASCII('A') - 1 + CASE rn % 26 WHEN 0 THEN 26 ELSE rn % 26 END) 
WHERE Status = 'A' AND Sequence_Code IS NULL
```

The `Sequence_Code` is generated with the row number, by the order of the column `Current_Year`, of each row in the table.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=beeb4e21e79344184b8fe720d9185f51).
Results:

```
> Sequence_Code |     ID | Current_Year | Record_Date | Status
> :------------ | -----: | -----------: | :---------- | :-----
> 17AA          | 310001 |         2017 | 2017-01-01  | S     
> 18AB          | 310002 |         2018 | 2018-02-22  | S     
> 19AC          | 310003 |         2019 | 2019-02-10  | S     
> 19AD          | 310004 |         2019 | 2019-02-20  | A     
> 20AE          | 310005 |         2020 | 2020-03-20  | S     
> 20AF          | 310006 |         2020 | 2020-04-20  | A
```

Comment: I tried this code,It's working but it's failing to generate next Code, if  the Sequence_code is 20AZ,Please Run this code by putting  '20AZ' in place of  '20AF',It should generate  '20BA' for the next row.

Comment: I have mentioned it in my question also,please see once "Alphabetic 'Sequence_Code' must be combination of last two digit of 'Current_Year' and 2 character alphabet like AA,AB,AC....AZ, BA,BB,BC...BZ. CA,CB,CC...."

Comment: @Alin I assumed that all the other rows have correct Sequence_Code. Isn't this the case?

Comment: That's correct @forpas ,But if my table has 26 rows,then deffinately it will generate till AZ, then for 27'th record,it should generate from BA, that's why i said to put 'AZ' in place of AF (just to understand the situation of 26th row).

Comment: @Alin Check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=800d21a450416a4f52c076228fcdf340 It generates BA for the last row.

Answer (score 3):

This is rather complicated.  I would start by generating all pairs to two characters.  Then do the following:

- Enumerate all the codes alphabetically.
- Find the maximum code currently being used.
- Enumerate the rows that have no sequence code
- Match back to the enumerated codes.

This works for any number of `NULL` values.

As a `select`, this looks like:

```
with alphas as (
      select convert(char(1), 'A') as chr
      union all
      select char(ascii(chr) + 1)
      from alphas
      where chr < 'Z'
     ),
     alpha2 as (
      select concat(a1.chr, a2.chr) as alpha2, row_number() over (order by a1.chr, a2.chr) as seqnum
      from alphas a1 cross join alphas a2
     )
select lda.*, alpha2.alpha2
from (select row_number() over (order by Current_Year, id) as seqnum, alpha2.seqnum as alpha2_maxseqnum, ld.*
      from (select ld.*, max(right(ld.Sequence_Code, 2)) over () as max_seq2
            from loaddata ld 
           ) ld join
           alpha2
           on alpha2.alpha2 = max_seq2
      where ld.Sequence_Code is null
     ) lda join
     alpha2 
     on lda.seqnum = alpha2.seqnum - lda.alpha2_maxseqnum ;
```

As an `update`:

```
with alphas as (
      select convert(char(1), 'A') as chr
      union all
      select char(ascii(chr) + 1)
      from alphas
      where chr < 'Z'
     ),
     alpha2 as (
      select concat(a1.chr, a2.chr) as alpha2, row_number() over (order by a1.chr, a2.chr) as seqnum
      from alphas a1 cross join alphas a2
     ),
     toupdate as (
      select lda.*, alpha2.alpha2
      from (select row_number() over (order by Current_Year, id) as seqnum, alpha2.seqnum as alpha2_maxseqnum, ld.*
            from (select ld.*, max(right(ld.Sequence_Code, 2)) over () as max_seq2
                  from loaddata ld 
                 ) ld join
                 alpha2
                 on alpha2.alpha2 = max_seq2
            where ld.Sequence_Code is null
           ) lda join
           alpha2 
           on lda.seqnum = alpha2.seqnum - lda.alpha2_maxseqnum 
      )
update toupdate
    set Sequence_Code = concat(right(current_year, 2), alpha2);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=783eeabe606d0cbda844e433a754f2c1) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Really Appreciate the effort u made to help me out.. when i am running the code it's showing a message like 'Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.'

(0 rows affected)

Comment: @Alin . . . Look at the db<>fiddle.  It works on the data you have provided in your question.